# Clang can't find head files in OSX and system integrity prevents me from moving them. How do I link them in Big Sur?

Tags: xcode, macos, clang

While building some package with clang I'm getting:

```
 fatal error: 'math.h' file not found
#include <math.h>
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I have already installed command line tools:

```
% xcode-select --install 
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

Now, I found [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557659/r-cant-update-packages-clang-cant-find-head-files) where they identify that the problem is that the header files are in the wrong place. Indeed I can find `math.h` in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include`. The same post identifies that system integrity prevents you from moving the files to `/usr/local/include`. Then some commenters suggest to use:

```
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -usr /
```

or

```
sudo installer -allowUntrusted -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
```

However I don't have the file `macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg` (or any similar file). Is that package not shipped anymore or am I missing something? Is there a legitimate way of moving the header files to the right spot without having to turn system integrity off?

---

Note I also learned that `/usr/local` is not used anymore by apple. So it seems like `/usr/local/include` would be them most appropriate target location for those files, since I'm sure it's in the path (as revealed by running clang with `-v`).

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm heading something similar and I'm kind of stuck

Comment: Unfortunately no. I had to go around it some other way.